# Show data base on Database

Tags: c#, database

I have a form with `ComboBox` to list items name and label `PRODUCTID` Value to describe its item `ID`:

[image: Form 1]

I have a class `Connect` to query. Here is the code:

```
class Connect
{
    SqlConnection con;
    public Connect()
    {
        String connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public DataTable executeSelect(String query)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        return dt;
    }

    public void execute(String query)
    {

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

My problems is I want my form to show its Product ID when i choose selected item in comboBox. And the data is the same with the data in database For example, I select Batman book in combo box, the label will show its Product ID and the ID must be the same in database. Could you please give me the example of code to solve this problem?? Thank you

Comment: I'm not seeing any ComboBoxes or ProductIDs in your code. What's the difference between a Product Type, ProductID, and ProductID value? Which one is “Batman book”?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void cboType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ptype = cboType.Text.ToString().Trim();
        //change query according to your db
        string sql = string.Format(@"select productid from yourtable where producttype = '{0}'", ptype);
        Connect con = new Connect();//you should learn ExecuteScalar method
        DataTable dt = con.executeSelect(sql);
        object id = dt.Rows[0][0];//assume data in db is consistent, 
        this.lblID.Text = id.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What the datatable code if the data isn't consistent? I'm a newbie haha